# __Rewire__ is not a function

Tags: javascript, testing, rewire

Using [Rewire](https://github.com/speedskater/babel-plugin-rewire) for testing..

Rewire is failing to rewire, and I'm wondering why.

**Here is an example of rewire failing:**

A file has a few exported functions...

```
export function foo() {}
export function bar() {}
export function baz() {}
```

In a test file...

```
import * as pathFileHelpers from 'path/to/file';

pathFileHelpers.__Rewire__({
   readFileSync: () => {
      return 'test test test'
    },
})
```

`_get__(...).__Rewire__ is not a function`

Why?